# Change background that specified for each tab whenever I click it using JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Can someone teach me how to create a jQuery that is no conflict in wordpress please?
I would love to add a new function on my tabs here on this [link](http://sevenseas-marine.com/services/):

A function that whenever I click one of those tabs, the main background changes, because I want it to replace my current slider on that page, and replace it with a big main background and it will change its background whenever I click one of those tabs that specified for it.

Also I like to learn a loading script similar to my homepage here that was created by a wordpress plugin: [Wordpress Plugin](http://sevenseas-marine.com)

I would like to learn this and apply it on the new function that I was talking about please. Thanks for your support!

Comment: What have you tried so far..? There are several guides out there if you want to learn jQuery. Start here: http://jquery.com/

Comment: I learned how the click events works on jquery, but im having a hard time when doing it on creating a background slideshow for tabs. And especially the loading scripts... i already went to that website, anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I think that you should try coming up with something, provide us with code examples / JsFiddle - and then get back to us. Your suggestion is quite vague and proposes that we should do the work for you. Google around a bit and you will find useful links, like so (with source code attached): http://www.freshdesignweb.com/fullscreen-jquery-slider.html